# Is there any way i can include the statement: ReactDOM.render(routing,document.getElementById("root")); without getting the error message

Tags: reactjs

i get the following error message in the browser :Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import "./index.css";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

const routing = (
  <Router>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Router>
);


ReactDOM.render(routing,document.getElementById("root"));



serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Seems like you are doing incorrect import. Check `App`, `Header` and `Footer`

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: this is App ``` import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If you are still facing the issue, please create a sandbox.

Comment: thnks for the help